# Open a Workbook and Save the Worksheets Into Separate CSV Files

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement to open an existing file from a different location and save each worksheet into different csv files in the name of the worksheet name (tab name).

```vb
Sub SplitFile()
    Dim vPath As String
    vPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works for the currently active workbook but I would like to process another workbook in a particular path.

I tried to assign a variable which holds the file path but it is throwing an error.

Comment: what do you mean by `another worksheet in some other path.`? Do you mean you have more workbooks that you want to run the code on? This is very unclear.

Comment: @MacroMan,  Sorry if it unclear.  The above code works for the workbook that is open.  I want to open a workbook in a particular path when this macro is run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a workbook variable and assign a workbook object to it:

```
Sub SplitFile()

Dim vPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbPath As Variant

wbPath = Application.GetOpenFileName("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")

If wbPath = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)

vPath = wb.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In wb.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As you can see, once you've assigned your workbook you just refer to that in your code wherever needed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I ran the code, it's throwing an error saying that it is runtime error 438.  Object doesn't support this property.  Any reason for it?